# Angular Material expandable datatable not displaying data

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I was trying to replicate this code [Angular Material Expandable Table](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-expandable-table-rows) with my own data from an API call but the data is getting sorted the wrong way. It should be returning an array of objects but its returning an array[] with what it seems is another array inside or something like that.

[image: console.log of rows]

component.ts

```
connect(): Observable<DegreeDetails[]> {
    const rows = [];
    this.registryService.getFullRegistryUniversity().forEach(degreeDetails => rows.push(degreeDetails, { detailRow: true, degreeDetails }));
    console.log(rows);
    return of(rows);
  }
```

registry.service.ts:

```
getFullRegistryUniversity():  Observable<DegreeDetails[]> {
    return this.http.get<DegreeDetails[]>(this.serviceUrl + 'fullregistryuniversity')
  }
```

component.html:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <ng-container matColumnDef="graduateRut">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let degreeDetails"> {{degreeDetails.graduateRut}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="major">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let degreeDetails"> {{degreeDetails.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="degreeStatus">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let degreeDetails"> {{degreeDetails.degreeStatus}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let detail"> 
        The symbol for {{detail.degreeDetails.major}}
      </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"
            matRipple 
            class="element-row" 
            [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
            (click)="expandedElement = row"></mat-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']; when: isExpansionDetailRow"
            [@detailExpand]="row.degreeDetails == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'"
            style="overflow: hidden"> 
    </mat-row>
  </mat-table>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to move part of the logic to the service:

```
connect(): Observable<DegreeDetails[]> {
    return this.registryService.getFullRegistryUniversity() 
  }

getFullRegistryUniversity():  Observable<DegreeDetails[]> {
    const rows = [];
    return this.http.get<DegreeDetails[]>(this.serviceUrl + 'fullregistryuniversity')
    .map(res => {
      res.forEach(degreeDetails =>  
        { console.log(degreeDetails)
          rows.push(degreeDetails, { detailRow: true, degreeDetails })}

        );
        console.log(rows);
        return rows;
    })
  }
```